# Как из исходного имени файла выводить только название без расширения?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php5

Название моего файла index.php, мне надо сделать index.txt

```
<?php
$filename = basename(__FILE__);
echo $filename;
?>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $filename = basename(__FILE__);
    echo $filename;

    $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);
    echo $withoutExt;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$filename = pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.txt';

echo $filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = basename(__FILE__, ".php"). '.txt';
```